# Cpp input until ctrl+d

Tags: c++, buffer, cin

How to pass last four values from entry into function distance as arguments?
For example if I enter values

2 6

1 2

4 8

I want the compiler to pick up last four values 1,2,4 and 8 and print (1,2) (4,8) =6.7
How to pick them up from buffer?

Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

struct point{

  int x1,x2;
  int y1,y2;



};

double distance(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2){

  double d=sqrt(pow((x1-x2),2)+pow((y1-y2),2));
  
   return (int)(d*10.0)/10.0;


}

int main(){

point a;


while(std::cin>>a.x1>>a.y1>>a.x2>>a.y2){


std::cout<<"Distance: "<< distance(a.x1,a.y1,a.x2,a.y2);

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to discard all input except the last 4 ints, or do you mean that you want to skip 2 and read the third thru sixth?  Either way, just write a loop to discard the desired data.  The first case is slightly more difficult; you'll need to store some elements.

Comment: FYI, prefer multiplication, `x * x`, to `pow(x,2)`.  The `pow` function is for floating point and may introduce errors when converting from or to integer.  Also, `x * x` and usually be performed by a couple of instruction.  The `pow` function requires setup instructions, call instructions, content instruction, and the return instructions.  Usually a lot more than a multiply.

Comment: Also, in most geometry and programming terms, a Point is usually `<x1, y1>` (for 2d Cartesion system).  A `Line` consists of 2 points; so you should name your structure as a `Line` and not a `point`.

Answer (score 1):

Try reading the first row and ignoring it:

```
std::string text_to_ignore;
std::getline(std::cin, text_to_ignore);
std::cin >> a.x1 >> a.y1 >> a.x2 >> a.y2;
```

Comment: In order to ignore a single line, it would probably be more efficient to call `std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' )`. However, this would require an additional header file to be included (`#include <limits>`).